# Cannot apply styles to elements within footer div

Tags: html, css

On [this simple site](http://www.napervillekingstaxi.com), I have made several changes without a hitch. The footer, however, is not cooperating. Nothing I do to the elements within the footer has any effect. At this point, I'm just trying to apply ANY property to the child elements to see if they hold, but to no avail. The only properties that are affecting the child elements are 4 properties applied to the parent `div`, the footer. These four properties are what's leading the child elements to take their current position:

```css
#footer {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

That's it! There's is nothing else I'm able to do. If I delete those properties, the child elements react accordingly, but there is no property I can apply to the child elements themselves for any change to occur. Does this have anything to do with the badges? What am I not seeing? I use Firebug through Firefox, and even there, when I click on the child elements, Firebug keeps showing me the CSS styles above, meaning the styles I'm writing for the child elements are not even being recognized.

Comment: where is the HTML part?

Comment: what extra property you are trying to add expect these 4 properties?

Comment: It looks like he applied some padding for #footer. He is expecting this padding should apply for each of the child element. For example, he added one <p>. For this he is expecting the same padding. CRAZY :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the problem on your site seems to be a missing closing parenthesis on the footer div.  It is causing the next rule to be ignored, which is having a cascading effect.

Fix these errors and you should be seeing the changes you apply:

[image: Screenshot of stylesheet issues napervillekingstaxi.com]

Comment: Omg! I can't believe it. I'm embarrassed that I couldn't figure this out.  Unbelievable.  I knew it was something small that I just couldn't catch. Thank you so much jme11! I'm so glad I came here! You have definitely relieved some stress.

Comment: Been there...sometimes you just need fresh eyes.  Much luck to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
.clearfix{clear:both;}

<div id="footer">
   <div style="float:left;width:50%;height:50px">11</div>
   <div style="float:left;width:50%;height:50px">111</div>
   <div class="clearfix></div>
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your css which might be causing all this:

```
#footer{
    width: auto;
    height:auto;
    font-family:Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#FFF;
    clear:both;
    background-color:#000;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    padding-top:4px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    a:link {             /* big no no... take this out of the #footer rules */
    color: #FF0;
    text-decoration: none; 
}
```